# Creating a "dedicated" LAN for a NAS

Tags: networking, lan, nas

A bit of context, most of my users are asked to move to online/cloud storage, except a few (4 actually), who use bigger files and therefore will be allowed to keep using LAN storage. 
The current setup is pretty slow and consume everyone's bandwidth.

The 4 of them use Windows 10 desktops with available PCIE x1 and x16 slots.

So my idea was to add a PCIE network card, a basic switch and a NAS to create their own little LAN, dedicated to their big files, while still being connected to the initial network with their integrated cards (and access internet through this one).

I've tried to make a mockup with VMs : 2 Windows 10 clients with 2 NIC (one in bridge mode, one in internal network).

With my little experiment I was able to ping the internal network cards between themselves and an WAN Ip, so I'd say my idea will work.

They are 4 currently, but picking a switch with 8 ports should provide enough room for (hypothetical) future hiring.

I have no experience with this kind of maneuver, is it recommended without a router ? Is it "clean" ? What's your opinion on this kind of layout ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is very good and separation of LANs for data and internet is applicable. Be aware you will need additional wires for this seconds (storage) LAN. such separation is used in enterprises for storage, app and admin networks (can be sometime also backup).

You can consider also using intelligent switch and play with VLANs for traffic separation.